# How to access outer container variables from a nested method

Tags: python

Consider:

```
 def outerMethod(outerParam):

   outerLocal = "foo"

   def innerMethod(innerParam):
      # locals() will not work here
      print("%(outerParam)s %(outerLocal) %(innerParam)" %locals())
```

What is the correct way to access the outerParam and outerLocal?

**UPDATE** The issue had to do with nested methods , so the question has been updated.

Comment: `my_param_var is not in locals` - Try printing `locals()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, you just have to use the right syntax for `%`:

```
>>> def foo(var):
...     car=3
...     print '%(var)s %(car)s' % locals()
...
>>> foo(123)
123 3
```

Comment: The syntax I had was correct. There is no problem with %locals()

Comment: I see the problem in mine was missing the `s` after the second and third parameters (not the first!) . It would have been helpful to have been more specific in pointing that out. But I'll award now in any case.